# Did Asp.net MVC Core works with Socket.io JS library?

Tags: socket.io, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I´ve an app that use in backend Node.js, and to communicate backend and frontend use Socket.io. Now I´m need to add new functionality that was run on Asp.net Core MVC. Now I need communicate with the frontend that run socket.io. Are there some libraries to communicate frontend with Socket.io js library and the backend Asp.net Core MVC? I´m trying to use SignalR with Asp.net Core MVC but I could not run together(MVC Core + SignalR).

Answer (score 0):

What SignalR are you using? ' Cause they are busy [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) with a special SignalR Server for ASP.NET Core. It's still a pre-release in beta.

Comment: I added an entry for myget V3 on Nuget.Config and started to use SignalR 3 beta version compatible with .Net Core
<add key="aspnetmaster" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />
Sorry for the delay

Comment: It looks like the SignalR Server link is dead. I believe they've moved everything over to https://github.com/aspnet/signalr anyway.